# PHP: Return multiple results by if else statement

Tags: php

What I want to achieve is to check multiple domain availability.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
//$domain = 'example.com';
$domain = array('example.com', 'foo.com');

if ( checkdnsrr(in_array($domain), 'ANY') ) {
  $echo_checkdnsrr = in_array($domain) . " DNS Record found (checkdnsrr)" . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
}
else {
  $echo_checkdnsrr = in_array($domain) . " NO DNS Record found (checkdnsrr)" . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
}

if ( gethostbyname(in_array($domain)) != in_array($domain) ) {
  $echo_gethostbyname = in_array($domain) . " DNS Record found (gethostbyname)" . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
}
else {
  $echo_gethostbyname = in_array($domain) . " NO DNS Record found (gethostbyname)" . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
}

$separator = "-------------------------------------------" . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;

print_r($echo_checkdnsrr);
print_r($echo_gethostbyname);
echo $separator;
?>
```

What I want to achieve:

```
example.com DNS Record found (checkdnsrr)
example.com DNS Record found (gethostbyname)
-------------------------------------------
foo.com DNS Record found (checkdnsrr)
foo.com DNS Record found (gethostbyname)
-------------------------------------------
```

Thank You for your help!

Thank You to @fluinc, here is my final code:

```
$domains = array('example.com', 'foo.com');

foreach ($domains as $domain) {
    if (checkdnsrr($domain, 'ANY') || gethostbyname($domain) != $domain) {
        echo "TAKEN " . $domain . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "AVAILABLE " . $domain . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

This is what it's returns:

```
TAKEN example.com
TAKEN foo.com
```

Later on it's super easy to import in excel, choose space as separator and find out the available domains with a query.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: I would start with a foreach() to loop through the domains in the array.

Comment: @BenPearlKahan It just returns "array DNS record found (checkdnsrr)\r\narray DNS record not found (gethostbyname)" I think it's messing up multiple results into one query. Somehow needs to echoing multiple results into multiple outputs.

Comment: Please add the error is question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a foreach to loop through the domains, Your use of in_array is wrong and not needed.

```
$domains = array('example.com', 'foo.com');

foreach ($domains as $domain) {
    if (checkdnsrr($domain, 'ANY')) {
        echo $domain . " DNS Record found (checkdnsrr)<br />". PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $domain . " NO DNS Record found (checkdnsrr)<br />". PHP_EOL;
    }

    if (gethostbyname($domain) != $domain) {
        echo $domain . " DNS Record found (gethostbyname)<br />". PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $domain . " NO DNS Record found (gethostbyname)<br />". PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo "-------------------------------------------<br />". PHP_EOL;
}
```

Updated as per comment

```
$domains = array('example.com', 'foo.com');

foreach ($domains as $domain) {
    if (checkdnsrr($domain, 'ANY') || gethostbyname($domain) != $domain) {
        echo $domain . " TAKEN<br />". PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $domain . " AVAILABLE<br />". PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo "-------------------------------------------<br />". PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thank You! Works like a charm! Is it possible only return something if one of the `checkdnsrr` or `gethostbyname` is true? Because this way only one line enough for one domain. So only will be enough `$domain . 'AVAILABLE'` and `$domain . 'TAKEN'`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `foreach()` and `echo` out each result as it is processed:

```
$domains = array('example.com', 'foo.com');

foreach($domains as $domain){
    if(checkdnsrr(in_array($domain), "ANY")){
        echo in_array($domain) . " DNS Record found (checkdnsrr)" . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo in_array($domain) . " NO DNS Record found (checkdnsrr)" . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    if(gethostbyname(in_array($domain)) != in_array($domain)) {
        echo in_array($domain) . " DNS Record found (gethostbyname)" . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo in_array($domain) . " NO DNS Record found (gethostbyname)" . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo "-------------------------------------------" . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Shorter:

```
$domains = array('example.com', 'foo.com');

foreach($domains as $domain){
    echo in_array($domain).(checkdnsrr(in_array($domain), "ANY") ? "NO " : "")."DNS Record found (checkdnsrr)" . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
    echo in_array($domain).(gethostbyname(in_array($domain))!= in_array($domain) ? "NO " : "")."Record found (gethostbyname)" . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "-------------------------------------------" . "<br />" . PHP_EOL;
}
```